# When to use SV or a GARCH model

Tags: volatility, time-series, garch, stochastic-volatility

So i have been searching for this answer for a question if there is a rule or something that would say when to use  GARCH type model or use an stochastic volatility model to predict the volatility of an asset. I know the main difference between this models which is that the first one models the volatility like and autoregresive processes and the second does it with an stochastic processes but i don't know when should I use a GARCH or when do I use a SV.